# django get token and userid after successful registration

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm building a server with custom registration pages using rest and django (latest versions).

I have 3 fields required (username unique, phone_number unique, password) and 1 optional.
Schema is:
User sends phone-number to server, we check if user exists and if don't - ask for registration. In both cases I want to send token and user_id as answer if credentials are correct.

The topics from 2016's are not working in my case, i think because of latest framework and python updates.

That's what i have now in `view.py`:

```
class RegisterView(APIView):
  renderer_classes = [renderers.JSONRenderer]

  def post(self, request):
    phone = request.POST.get('phone')
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    name = request.POST.get('name', '')
    try:
        ChatUser.objects.create_user(username, phone, password, name)
        return Response({'success': True, 'token': """THERE SHOULD BE TOKEN"""})
    except Exception:
        return Response({'success': False})

class CheckPhone(APIView): # works fine 
    renderer_classes = [renderers.JSONRenderer]

    def post(self, request):
        phone_number = request.POST.get('phone_number')
        try:
            User.objects.get(phone=phone_number)
            return Response("""asks for login""")
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response("""asks for registration""")
```

`models.py`:

```
class ChatUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, username, phone, password, name, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given phone and password."""
        if not phone:
            raise ValueError('The given phone must be set')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
        username = self.model.normalize_username(username)
        user = self.model(phone=phone, username=username, name=name, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return username

    def create_user(self, username, phone, password, name, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given phone and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(username, phone, password, name, **extra_fields)

class ChatUser(AbstractUser):
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['phone', 'name']

    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group,
        verbose_name=_('groups'),
        blank=True,
        help_text=_(
            'The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions '
            'granted to each of their groups.'
        ),
        related_name="chatuser_set",
        related_query_name="user",
    )
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Permission,
        verbose_name=_('user permissions'),
        blank=True,
        help_text=_('Specific permissions for this user.'),
        related_name="chatuser_set",
        related_query_name="user",
    )
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=25, unique=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?7?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+71234567890'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone = models.CharField(_('phone_number'), validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, unique=True) # validators should be a list
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    objects = ChatUserManager()
```

So, how can I get token and user_id in these cases and, also, did I miss anything while creating custom models?

Comment: Why don't you just reuse the `django.contrib.auth.db.models.User` in Django the preferred practice to extend it is to create `user = models.OneOnOneField` in the extending model - see here https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: Then `user_id` is in your models's `user.id` and token - see how DRF creates tokens, you can add any other fields in your child model as per need if they are not in Django's User model.

Comment: @dmitryro I'm not sure if I can login using OOOF with phone+special code(not password) and get token for authentification

Comment: Models are not a problem here, I just want to have more flexible authentication and manage tokens not only when logging in

Comment: May be this is not the root of your problem but in `REQUIRED_FIELDS` **should not contain the USERNAME_FIELD or password** (so get rid of the password field), can you add `traceback` of the error or other relevant details.

Comment: @YusefBH there are no errors, when I submit descent post request with credentials (username + password) to `auth_views.obtain_auth_token` it simply returns token, but I don't understand how to send it right after registration (to skip 1 step) and also I want to manage tokens in future. An example from rest library doesn't seem to be useful
Also I can't send user_id as it returns None (`request.user.id`). as for Now these are the only problems
I've updated a code a little bit but the questions are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the token using `from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token`

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

class RegisterView(APIView):
  renderer_classes = [renderers.JSONRenderer]

  def post(self, request):
    phone = request.POST.get('phone')
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    name = request.POST.get('name', '')
    try:
        chat_user = ChatUser.objects.create_user(username, phone, password, name)
        token = Token.objects.create(user=chat_user)
        return Response({'success': True, 'token': token.key})
    except Exception:
        return Response({'success': False})
```

**Edit**:

```
def _create_user(self, username, phone, password, name, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given phone and password."""
        if not phone:
            raise ValueError('The given phone must be set')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
        username = self.model.normalize_username(username)
        user = self.model(phone=phone, username=username, name=name, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

You should return `user` **not** `username`

I hope this will help.

Comment: `File "/Users/vladislavmilenin/Desktop/matchbot/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 210, in __set__
    self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "'persikalda2'": "Token.user" must be a "ChatUser" instance.
'
"persikalda2" - username sent by POST

Comment: Yes, thanks. A problem with token is solved (don't even know why there was username). I suppose this token doesn't have expiry date and I can't generate new if need to?

Comment: Your welcome. No it doesn't have expiry date, but i guess you can subclass the `Token` class

Comment: is there any easy way to have an access with phone_number instead of username when needed? I mean having an option to access single account with both (make optional)?

Comment: You mean authenticating using either `username` or `phone`? if this what you meant, then you could create a [custom authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend)